# SIGTERM not reported as 143 during trap

Tags: bash, shell, sigterm

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Running $(basename $0) $*"

function on_err {
echo $?
echo "error happened"

}


trap "on_err" 2 15
while true
do
:
done

$ kill -15 pid
```

gives

```
0
error happened
```

I was hoping to see

```
143
error happened
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something in while loop instead spinning infinite.

```
while true
do
 sleep 1
done
```

use `kill -15 -PID` instead `kill -15 PID`

**Output:**

```
Running test.sh 
0
Terminated: 15
143
```

Comment: Why should that matter ?

Comment: Why should doing something in while loop matter ?

Comment: This is from bash man page: `if bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the command completes`